# div:after do not show image with background-size: cover

Tags: css, background-image, opacity

I wanted to show a background image with opacity setting, so I used this code

Mark up:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="BackLayer">
         <section id="galleria">
             <div class="title-box">
                 <h1 id="galleria-title">Galleria a Arte Studio Invernizzi</h1>
             </div>
         </section>
    ...
```

CSS:

```
#galleria:before {
   content : "";
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: url('images/00-Tremlett-Verjux-2013.jpg') no-repeat;
   width: 587px;
   height: 400px;
   opacity : 0.2;
}
```

It works fine, BUT I need to set the image as background-size: cover... (I want to do something similar to http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB048M27G)

If I simply add background-size: cover, the width property overrides it (or so I guess... anyway, it does not work); if I do not set any width/height, the image do not show up...

This problem has been giving me a big headache... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the position absolute in :

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;

bottom: 0; /* add this */
right: 0; /* add this */
```

instead using the width/height